# PHP - How to count lines of code in an application

Tags: php, code-snippets

I need to count the number of lines of code within my application (in PHP, not command line), and since the snippets on the web didn't help too much, I've decided to ask here.
Thanks for any reply!

**EDIT**

Actually, I would need the whole snippet for scanning and counting lines within a given folder. I'm using this method in CakePHP, so I'd appreciate seamless integration.

Comment: Do you want actual lines of code? Including/Excluding comments? Inc/Exc blanks? Inc/Exc multi-line strings? There's many different definitions of "line" when it comes to source code.

Comment: All lines, whether they contain code, comments or are blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it over a directory, I'd use an iterator.

```
function countLines($path, $extensions = array('php')) {
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)
    );
    $files = array();
    foreach ($it as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir() || $file->isDot()) {
            continue;
        }
        $parts = explode('.', $file->getFilename());
        $extension = end($parts);
        if (in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
            $files[$file->getPathname()] = count(file($file->getPathname()));
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

That will return an array with each file as the key and the number of lines as the value.  Then, if you want only a total, just do `array_sum(countLines($path));`...

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I didn't quite get what the RecursiveIteratorIterator class does and if it could be replaced with something that could easily integrate with CakePHP (As I mentioned in the question, I would appreciate not including any other 'foreign' class in my application).

Comment: The 'foreign' class is a part of PHP itself. As for integrating with Cake, you can't get much simpler than copy-pasting that function.

Comment: @linkyndy: `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` are both [core PHP classes](http://us.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) since `PHP 5.0.0`.  There's no need to include any foreign classes.  Just copy and past the code above and it will work for any framework (since it's just raw PHP)...

Comment: I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::isDot() in` - Why???

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `file` function to read the file and then `count`:

```
$c = count(file('filename.php'));
```

Comment: I've edited the question since it was not very clear :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$fp = "file.php";
$lines = file($fp);
echo count($lines);
```

Comment: I've edited the question since it was not very clear :)

Answer (score 3):

Using ircmaxell's code, I made a simple class out of it, it works great for me now

```
<?php
class Line_Counter
{
    private $filepath;
    private $files = array();

    public function __construct($filepath)
    {
        $this->filepath = $filepath;
    }

    public function countLines($extensions = array('php'))
    {
        $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->filepath));
        foreach ($it as $file)
        {
           // if ($file->isDir() || $file->isDot())
           if ($file->isDir() )
            {
                continue;
            }
            $parts = explode('.', $file->getFilename());
            $extension = end($parts);
            if (in_array($extension, $extensions))
            {
                $files[$file->getPathname()] = count(file($file->getPathname()));
            }
        }
        return $files;
    }

    public function showLines()
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->countLines());
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    public function totalLines()
    {
        return array_sum($this->countLines());
    }

}

// Get all files with line count for each into an array
$loc = new Line_Counter('E:\Server\htdocs\myframework');
$loc->showLines();

echo '<br><br> Total Lines of code: ';
echo $loc->totalLines();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP Classes has a nice class for counting lines for php files in a directory:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1091-PHP-Calculates-the-total-lines-of-code-in-a-directory.html

You can specify the file types you want to check at the top of the class.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but since I am integrating this in CakePHP, it will be more appropriate if I don't import a separate class for achieving this :)

Comment: You can always look at the code and implement the parts you want, it's pretty small :-)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc

Comment: I need to integrate it easier with CakePHP :)

Comment: Then you can look at the code and integrate it.

Comment: This repository has been archived by the owner on Jan 10, 2023. But Sebastian Bergmann created similar tool: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/lines-of-code

Answer (score 0):

a little dirty, but you can also use system / exec / passthru `wc -l *`

Comment: I mentioned that I need a PHP snippet, not a command line input. Sorry!