# Get the count of sub-folders

Tags: php, count, glob

I was using `count(glob("test/*"))` to count the sub-folders in the `test` folder, but now that I also have files in the `test` folder, not just folders, I get incorrect results. Is there a way to modify the `glob` pattern so that it'll return only the folders, not files?

I've thought about a workaround. Get the total count of folders and files, get the count of files only, and then, subtract the count of files from the count of the whole.

```
$total_items  = count(glob("test/*"));
$total_files  = count(glob("test/*.*"));
$folder_count = $total_items - $total_files;
```

This works, but there might be a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use the option `GLOB_ONLYDIR` to return only directories:

```
$total_items  = count( glob("test/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) );
```

Comment: This is nice ☺ ☻. However, it doesn't count deeper in subfolders ... but this approach has helped me to do so by also combining it with this other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4339437/1883256).

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution may fail if there is a directory with a dot in its name like `some.dir`. For better results, you can check each of the results to see if they are files. Something like:

```
count(array_filter(glob("test/*"), "is_dir"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this, using readdir() and test with is_dir() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)

```
$dir = "test";
$n = 0;
$dh = opendir($dir);
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) {
        $n++;
    }
}
closedir($dh);
echo $n . " subdirectories in " . $dir;
```